# Django CMS and regular django view by ajax

Tags: django-cms

I want to run some code by ajax in my DjangoCMS app. How can I do this best?

I've tried add normally django view which return:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

And add this view to my urls:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'test_json/', MyJSONView)
)
```

But when I've tried

```
localhost:8000/en/test_json/
```

I got

```
CMS Page not found: /en/test_json/
Raised by:  cms.views.details
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I got this.
'cms.urls' must be the last in urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'test_json/', MyJSONView)
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```